# BufferedReader read value inbetween a tag with attributes and replace it

Tags: java, bufferedreader

i am using JAVA bufferedreader to read through a text file, the format/layout of the text file  is in xml. i want search for the following line:

```
<element id="ID">1</Element>
```

and replace  "1" with "2"

```
<property name="seed">2</property>
```

but cant seem to work my way round it.

```
    try {

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(f));
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(w));

            String s = "";
            String seed="";


            while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                if(s.contains("<element id="ID">1</Element>
")){
                    System.out.println(s);
                    s= s.replace("<element id="ID">1</Element>
    ", "<element id="ID">2</Element>
    ");

                }
```

Comment: you need to escape " character with \"

Comment: thnx but got it to work but the following code,

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(s.contains("ID")){

            s= s.replace(">1<", ">"+2+"<");


        }
```